# ClassCastException in Listview

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

Following code generates exception as:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to vro.nagainfo.vromain.model.VROUser.
```

listUsers is a custom listview and VROUser is a class

```
listUsers.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                VROUser user = (VROUser) listUsers.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProfileViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userId", user.getUserID());
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

How to fix this?

Comment: what is VROUser ? getter setter class ?

Comment: Add the part of code that yoy are using to populate listUsers. Probably in someplace you are adding an integer

Comment: use onclick in base adapter class

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing with this code???

```
   VROUser user = (VROUser) listUsers.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Use like this

```
 VROUser user = listUsers.get(position);
```

Use it

Comment: listview shows successfully...exception generates when OnItemClickListener call

Comment: VROUser contains the details of selected item..call to get more details of selected item and it displayed on  ProfileViewActivity activity

Comment: Details are stored inside ArrayList?

Comment: Do one thing remove this line and then try this code. It will Work. Ad you are trying to set Value Integer type to VROUser

Comment: VROUser  is this your Bean Class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79763/discussion-between-rishi-paul-and-krishna).

Answer (score 0):

`ClassCastException`  means you are declaring a variable of some type and assigning it to another type you have defined in a layout xml file...

Example in your xml:

```
<Button
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/btn1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</Button>
```

And in your java code

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView)context.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

There is no compile error. But you are face `ClassCastException`

Check your ListVIew. How did you declare in both xml and java code

Answer (score 0):

Correct:

```
VROUser user = listUsers.get(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, `listUsers.getItemAtPosition(position);` it is giving integer value,but  you have casted to VROUser.

Comment: what are you returning in getItem in the adapter?